# Android spinner dropdown menu background color change

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner, background-color

I want to change a spinner's dropdown menu background color without changing the background color of the spinner itself (it's transparent). Is it possible?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Yep, it's possible. Use `android:popupBackground` on the Spinner in your XML or  `setPopupBackgroundResource(int)` in code.

Answer (score 5):

To change the background color of the drop-down list, add `android:colorBackground` parameter to the theme in your **styles.xml**

**Code:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

Thus, the overall style is preserved: the effect when pressed, rounded corners, etc.

**Screenshot:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using Material Design 3 responsible attribute is:

```
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/foo</item>
```