# How to set rounded corners for Spinner DropDown?

Tags: android

I need to customize spinner DropDown. It should be wits rounded corners.
Now it looks like this:

[Closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyK4F.png)

[Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A118.png)

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218489/android-spinner-dropdown-menu-background-color-change) doesn't work.

Layout:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/messageSubject"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Text.Default.Normal"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/grid_6_25"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_1_75"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/supportQuestion" />
```

Fragment:

```
class SupportFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_support) {

private val viewBinding by viewBinding<FragmentSupportBinding>()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    initView()
}

private fun initView() {
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        requireContext(),
        R.array.message_subject,
        R.layout.spinner_selected
    ).also { adapter ->
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown)
    }

    viewBinding.messageSubject.adapter = NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(requireContext(), adapter, R.layout.spinner_hint)
}

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = SupportFragment()
}
```

}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Create a Round Background **spinnerbg.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="#3B3B3B" />
   <corners android:radius="@dimen/_4sdp" />
   </shape>
   ```
2. Add it to Styles.

   ```
   <style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinnerbg
    </item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/spinnerbg
    </item>

    <item name="android:textAlignment">textStart</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. Use the style

   ```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
   android:id="@+id/spinner_season"
   style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
   android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
   android:layout_gravity="end"
   android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
   android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
   ```

In the java file Add your custom layout if you need.

```
    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.item_spinner, R.id.textview, season1);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner_dropdown);
```

Comment: nothing changed [link](https://umbrellait.rapira.com/9yjy6L)

Comment: remove this in your code.
    android:background="@color/transparent"

Comment: I have given you a working code implement it properly

Answer (score 0):

Create a background.xml finl and set this to the spinner background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:radius="30dp"/>

    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>

    <stroke
        android:color="@color/colorGray"
        android:width="2dp"/>

</shape>
```

@color/colorWhite and @color/colorGray you can choose accordingly to your needs.

Then set it like this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/messageSubject"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Text.Default.Normal"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/grid_6_25"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_1_75"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/supportQuestion" />
```

Comment: I need make rounded [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A118.png)

Comment: Then simply add this android:background="@drawable/background" to the specified layout which you want to make round

Comment: I need add corners to popup. How to find out popup layout? setPopUpBackground doesn't work for me.

Comment: Where you kept <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner share the whole layout file

Comment: when i do this - changes bg only for closed spinner [screen](https://umbrellait.rapira.com/t1CzfF) for open spinner nothing changed [screenshot](https://umbrellait.rapira.com/8wEPkK)

Comment: Set android:background="@drawable/background" to the root view of the layout it will do the work

Answer (score 0):

Just use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner` not `Spinner`, and set rounded background.